# How to set the width of an input text field in an inline form?

Tags: lightning-design-system

I like to have an inline form but with a long input text field. I tried this and failed so far:

```
<form className="slds-form--inline slds-grid slds-nowrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
    <div className="slds-form-element slds-size--5-of-6">
        <label className="slds-form-element__label" htmlFor="plugin-url-input">From URL</label>
        <div className="slds-form-element__control">
            <input className="slds-input" id="plugin-url-input" ref="pluginUrl" type="text" name="plugin-url"
                   placeholder="http://my-page.com/myPlugin.js"
                   defaultValue="plugins/TestWidgetPlugin.js"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="slds-form-element  slds-size--1-of-6">
        <button className="slds-button slds-button--brand" onClick={() => props.loadPlugin(this.refs.pluginUrl.value)}
             tabIndex="0">
            Load Plugin
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add `slds-size--1-of-1` class in your `input` tag's or the div's class list.

Comment: Adding `1-of-2` to the control div: `"slds-form-element__control slds-size--1-of-2"` makes it wider, but adding `1-of-1` does lead to a linebreak after the label.  ...

Comment: You can add `display: inline-flex;` in style of `<div className="slds-form-element slds-size--5-of-6">` div to prevent line breaking.